# Appcelerator android.settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS not working

Tags: android, appcelerator

In appcelerator I want to open application details page in settings whats the best way to do it?

Android 6.x

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
  action: 'android.settings.APPLICATION_SETTINGS',
});
intent.addFlags(Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

Brings me to general app settings page where all app are listed

but what I need is to direct them to specifically to current app settings

as per android docs is should be 
    action: 'android.settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS',

but its not working in Appcelerator

SDK 5.3 / 5.4

Answer (score 2):

```
var intentData = {action: 'android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS', data: 'package:' + Ti.App.getId()};
var flags = [Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY, Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS];
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent(intentData);
intent.flags = flags;
yourWindow.activity.startActivity(intent);
```

1. You cant trust currentActivity any more
2. Need to be sure the settings app knows what app you want details for
3. Works with 5.5.1.GA